# Android string format with ValueAnimator

Tags: android, formatting, android-resources

I want to show a price by using String resource with ValueAnimator. 
The output what i expect is like this : **(123,432,133)**

**strings_format.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="price_format">%,s</string>
    
</resources>
```

**ValueAnimator**

```
private fun setAnimatedTextView(
initialValue: Int = 0,
finalValue: Int = 0,
textView: TextView
) {
  ValueAnimator.ofInt(initialValue, finalValue).apply {
      duration = 1_000
      addUpdateListener {
          textView.text = requireContext().getString(R.string.price_format, it.animatedValue.toString())
      }
  }.start()
}
```

But if i run this code, it makes `FormatFlagsConversionMismatchException`. 
How can i make it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a mistake. 
First of all, i changed the `strings_format.xml` like this.

```
<resources>

    <string name="price_format">%,d</string>
    
</resources>
```

and the part of using ValueAnimator is like this.

```
    private fun setAnimatedTextView(
    initialValue: Int = 0,
    finalValue: Int = 0,
    textView: TextView
) {
  ValueAnimator.ofInt(initialValue, finalValue).apply {
      duration = 1_000
      addUpdateListener {
          textView.text = String.format(requireContext().getString(R.string.price_format, it.animatedValue.toString().toInt()))
      }
  }.start()
}
```